# Como acceder a un QPushButton desde un modulo externo creado por mi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Quisiera crear un modulo externo para mi programa main.py. Un modulo que contenga la función 'def limpiar():' con un QPushButton y que borre los datos, ('') de un QLineEdit que está en la clase main.py.

main.py
import sys, os, gc
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from Calcul_pue2 import VentanaPrincipal
from Limpiar import *

```
class Calcul_pueApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = VentanaPrincipal()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint |
                            Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(1050, 750)
               
        self.ui.mni_netejar.triggered.connect(self.limpiar)
        self.ui.linEd_QIT_03A.setText('123456')

    def limpiar(self):
        self.ui.linEd_QIT_03A.setText('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Calcul_pueApp()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mod limpiar.py

```
def limpiar():

        self.ui.linEd_QIT_03A.setText('')
```

la función limpiar no encuentra el LinEd_QIT_03A y no se como hacer para que se pueda ejecutar desde el modulo externo.

Saludos.

El programa Pricipal.py funciona bien. si pulso en el boton de menu: self.ui.mni_netejar.triggered.connect(self.limpiar) el texto que hay en el lineEd_QIT_03A que es '123456' se borra correctamente, pero si ejecuto la funcion limpiar desde un modulo externo no funciona. No encuentra LinEdit_QIT_03A.

Perdón. Envié el código con errores por culpa de tantas pruebas que hice.
Lo muestro corregido:

Principal.py

```
import sys, os, gc
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from Calcul_pue2 import VentanaPrincipal
from Limpiar import limpiar   

class Calcul_pueApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = VentanaPrincipal()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint |
                            Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(1050, 750)
               
        self.ui.mni_netejar.triggered.connect(self.limpiar)
        self.ui.linEd_QIT_03A.setText('123456')

   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Calcul_pueApp()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Limpiar.py

def limpiar():
        linEd_QIT_03A.setText('')
```

Lo que me gustaría es que la función de limpiar pueda crearla en un módulo externo. el botón de limpiar(Netejar) está en el menú de la ventana principal y el lineEd_QIT_03A tambien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el código que ya has escrito.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de haberte entendido bien, pero prueba esto:

**main.py**

```
import sys
# ??? import os, gc
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QInputDialog, QMessageBox, \
    QFileDialog, QLineEdit, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, \
    QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# ??? from Calcul_pue2 import VentanaPrincipal

from limpiar import Calcul_limpiar                                     # +++


#class Calcul_pueApp(QMainWindow, VentanaPrincipal):
class Calcul_pueApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)

        self.centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centrawidget)

# ???        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | 
# ???                            Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint |
# ???                            Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
# ???        self.setFixedSize(950, 650)

        self.mni_netejar = QPushButton('Show limpiar')
        self.mni_netejar.clicked.connect(self.limpiar_show)
        
        self.linEd_QIT_03A = QLineEdit()
        self.linEd_QIT_03A.setText('123456')
        
        self.calcul_limpiar = Calcul_limpiar(self)                     # +++
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centrawidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.linEd_QIT_03A)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mni_netejar)

    def limpiar_show(self):
        self.calcul_limpiar.show()                                     # +++
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Calcul_pueApp()
    w.show()
    w.resize(600, 400)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**limpiar.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, \
    QGridLayout


class Calcul_limpiar(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.parent = parent

        self.centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centrawidget)
        
        self.mni_netejar = QPushButton('Clear linEd_QIT_03A')
        self.mni_netejar.clicked.connect(self.clear_linEd)
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centrawidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mni_netejar)

    def clear_linEd(self):
        self.parent.linEd_QIT_03A.clear()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias S.Nick. El código que has puesto funciona exactamente como tu propones y tomo nota, pero lo que yo necesito es eso pero sin nueva ventana. Solo ejecutar la función 'limpiar' desde un módulo.